# Set list size from another list size or int?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have tow lists in my script.

```
public List<GameObject> l1 = new List<GameObject>();
public List<GameObject> l2= new List<GameObject>();
```

I want to set `l2` list size from `l1` list size.
I've tried  `list.Capacity` but when I run the game the list size still showing 0 in Unity inspector 
But when I debug `list.Capacity` it's showing to my my value.
So I want to set my list size from C#.

Comment: There is no need for micro-optimizations.  If you're list is going to be expanding just let it expand, if you want to default it select a const which you think would be reasonable.

Comment: Do you mean size or do you mean capacity? Because the only way to "set the size" of a .NET list is to add elements to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `List.Count` to set the capacity of `l2` in the `List` constructor and that must be done in a function. It take the size of `l1` from the Editor and use it to set size of `l2`.

*To change the Capacity*:

```
public List<GameObject> l1 = new List<GameObject>();
public List<GameObject> l2;

void Start()
{
    l2 = new List<GameObject>(l1.Count);
    Debug.Log("Capacity: " + l2.Capacity);
}
```

*To copy the values too (This will change the Count or Size seen in the Editor*:

```
public List<GameObject> l1 = new List<GameObject>();
public List<GameObject> l2;

void Start()
{
    l2 = new List<GameObject>(l1.Count);
    Debug.Log("Capacity: " + l2.Capacity);

    for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
    {
        l2.Add(l1[i]);
    }
    Debug.Log("Count: " + l2.Count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I've tried 'l2 = new List<GameObject>(l1.Count);
    Debug.Log("Capacity: " + l2.Capacity);' but not works but I had solved my problem with copy the values.

Answer (score 0):

At the crux of the matter here is confusion as to what capacity, count, and size of a list means. Setting capacity of a list will do nothing to affect the actual size of the list. The size of the list is 0 because nothing has been added to the list. The Size (i.e. Count) of a list is dynamic, if you keep adding items to the list, it'll automatically increase. This is different from an array where the size is static.

The capacity of a list is used for optimizing performance of a list. I.e. if you know there will only be X many entries in the list, you can set capacity to X. However, if you added more entries than X, the list would need to restructure to handle additional entries. This is done automatically for you.

If you want a datastructure with a static size, an Array would be a better choice.

Comment: Look very close at the question. OP wants to make them have the-same **Capacity** not **Count**.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify the misunderstanding.